# Не получается проигнорировать папку в .gitignore?

Tags: git

У меня есть такая структура проекта 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно проигнорировать папку LOGS и файл в ней `logs.txt`
В `.gitignore` прописал следующее, но при `git push` файл всё равно отслеживается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вы их сначала удалите из индекса. `git rm -fr practice/LOGS; git commit -s ...`.

Comment: @0andriy верно.

Comment: Возможно, после LOGS/ закрался пробел. Да и сама строчка не завершена - нет перевода строки. Или где-то ещё лежит файл гитигнор, который перекрывает этот файл.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно указали путь, вот так должно работать:

```
LOGS/logs.txt
```

или:

```
LOGS/*
```

Comment: Пробовал и так писать. Файл всё равно попадает под отслеживание.

Comment: Проект `domains`? Тогда путь прописан правильно!

Comment: Проект practice

Comment: @СергейСушко, где расположен каталог `.git`?

Comment: В папке domains
Я указываю в игноре папки относительно файла .gitignore
.gitignore лежит на одном уровне с папкой practice, в которой и находится папка LOGS

Удалил из индекса, но всё равно показывает, что новые файлы